# QWebView with YouTube

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

In my program, I have a QWebView that displays a YouTube video. The code I use has worked perfectly fine for me in the past, however one day I noticed it wasn't working anymore. I have Flash installed, and other websites (google) load just fine. Here is my code:

```
QNetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true);
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
ui->webView->load(QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/abakM9O_Bos"));
ui->webView->setEnabled(true);
```

Can anyone explain why this used to work for me in the past but now it isn't? I tried http and https with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would look into:

- Do other video sites work? (Vimeo, for example)
- Are you viewing the YouTube videos through flash, or HTML5?
- Can you confirm that your web view is loading your flash plugin by going to one of the flash test pages?
- Does it work with the Qt web browser example project?

If none of those point you in the right direction, I would definitely consider going to QtWebEngine. QtWebEngine is built using the Chromium platform, and is able to handle complex webpages really well. I've also noticed that QtWebEngine is significantly faster and more stable that the old QtWebKit based widgets. Plus, QtWebKit is no longer going to be updated, so if you're building a new application, it might be better to start with the newer system. Hopefully this helps!

**Update**
Just to summarize what has been stated in the comments:

- This is likely an HTML5 issue, where QtWebKit doesn't have the H.264 codec built in.
- As a result, you need to ship your application with the codecs you need. Specifically, I'd suggest ffmpeg (ffmpegsumo.dll), as this is what Chrome uses.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it with Vimeo and it did not load either. This make me think is has something to do with flash (or HTML5, not sure how to tell). When I used a flash test page, it worked, but said I was using Flash 14, yet when viewing normally on Chrome it says Flash 16. I tried to install it manually, but the installer wasn't loading and I manually disabled the updater cus it was annoying me. You think I need to find a way to update to 16 for it to work? I'm also not making a new application, in fact, I'm closing this one down but displaying a vid to the newer application I made already.

Comment: In that case, it's probably not a Flash issue, but instead an HTML5 issue. Both YouTube and Vimeo have recently switched to using HTML5 players by default. If this is in fact the case, you'll need to manually install codecs, since Qt doesn't ship with them by default. YouTube and many others use H.264, so that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Is there any way to do this easily? I can't depend on any new external files of dll's.

Comment: Somehow you're going to need to bundle the codecs with your application. If you can statically link the codecs in, then that should work. Looking at Chrome, it appears they use ffmpeg (ffmpegsumo.dll). I'd take a look at that.

Comment: I recommend you to build Qt5 and newest version of QtWebKit module.
Problem is that Youtube no longer uses adobe flash for video playback, but HTML5.